# How to avoid double counting while using SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a transaction table which contains date, transaction_id and category (it is a sales table of clothes). It looks like this:

| ndate | transaction_id | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 111 | M |
| 11 | 111 | F |
| 11 | 112 | M |
| 12 | 113 | F |
| 12 | 113 | O |
| 13 | 114 | M |

I am applying a sql query to aggregate the data and make a new table to reduce the number of rows (as the data is too huge):

```
select ndate, category, count(distinct transaction_id)
from transaction_table
group by ndate, category;
```

The output that I am getting is this:

| ndate | category | transactions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | M | 2 |
| 11 | F | 1 |
| 12 | F | 1 |
| 12 | O | 1 |
| 13 | M | 1 |

As you can see from the transaction_table there have been only 4 transactions but in the output_table the total count of transaction is 6 which is wrongly been done due to the group by of category.

This is the output I am trying to get, I am not sure if a table like this can be made in sql (I am new to sql) :

[desired output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHyr3.png)

| ndate | Total transactions | category | transactions by category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 2 | M | 2 |
|  |  | F | 1 |
| 12 | 1 | F | 1 |
|  |  | O | 1 |
| 13 | 1 | M | 1 |

Comment: Tag spam doesn't help us help you; it makes it harder to. Tagging multiple conflicting tags means that we have no idea what technology you are really asking about, making your question unclear and difficult to answer. Tagging completely irrelevant technologies just wastes the time of the subject experts you attract that know nothing about the technology you are *actually* asking about. Either way, tag spam can easily end up attracting downvotes and also close votes if they make the question unclear. Just tag the technologies you are actually asking about.

Comment: I have removed the conflicting tags, apart from [[tag:sql]]. [Edit[ your questions and tag correctly.

Comment: Also, don't use images for text. if you want to supply sample data, use DDL and DML statements. And for expected results use well formatted tabular `text` or a markdown table.

Comment: There is no way to answer this question -- you have multiple categories per transaction --what do you mean by not get rid of them?  What should we do with them?  WHAT EXACTLY IS YOUR EXPECTED OUTPUT?

Comment: If you remove the word distinct, does it give you the result youre looking for? EDIT: Oh i see what you mean I think. 1 Transaction is either on multiple dates or multiple categories.  IF 1 transaction can be in multiple dates, which date do you want ot count it under?  IF 1 transaction can be in multiple categories, which category do you want to count it under? by GROUP BY you are forcing yourself to make a choice, you cant count it as both unless you want to split 1 transaction into a decimal and count 0.5 transactions in 2 categories, for instance

Comment: Hey josh I think your way of using decimals might do the trick for me, but how do I write the code for it?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result. (I can't figure out what you expect to be returned.)

Comment: I have uploaded my desired output table, please help.

Comment: Can you please use properly formatted text this time too. (Instead of that link to an image.)

Comment: Also, add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: Do you really want NULL values for some ndate and Total transactions? That's not really the way SQL is supposed to be used. Fix it in the presentation layer instead,

Comment: The dataset is too large to be fixed in the presentation layer, that's why I just need a roundabout way to get the correct numbers. Please help me with the code (even if there are null values)

Answer (score 3):

```
select ndate, category,
    count(distinct transaction_id) as category_transactions,
    (
        select count(distinct transaction_id)
        from transaction_table t2
        where t2.ndate = t.ndate
    ) as ndate_transactions
from transaction_table t
group by ndate, category;
```

Or this should work but I can't promise it's faster/cheaper to run:

```
with data as (
    select ndate, category,
        dense_rank() over (partition by ndate order by transaction_id) as dr
    from transaction_table
), data2 as (
    select ndate, category,
        count(distinct dr) as category_transactions, max(dr) as max_dr
    from data
    group by ndate, category
)
select ndate, category, category_transactions,
    max(max_dr) over (partition by ndate) as ndate_transactions
from data2
```

To suppress repeated values you'd generally just use a `lag()`:

```
case when ndate = lag(ndate) then null else ndate end
```

Comment: Both queries work, at least with Postgresql. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=809ef5218cf4f2a3bb725b2b3c13f484

Answer (score 2):

Consider below for BigQuery

```
select ndate, total_transactions,
  array(
    select as struct category, 
      count(distinct transaction_id) as transactions_by_category
    from t.arr
    group by category
  ) as transactions
from (
  select ndate, 
    count(distinct transaction_id) total_transactions,
    array_agg(struct(category, transaction_id)) arr
  from transaction_table
  group by ndate
) t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Can we get the columns in transactions column (i.e., category, transaction_by_category) at the top instead of them being repeated in each ndate row?

Comment: nope. the way how you shown the desired output - can be achieved only via use of repeated record

Answer (score 0):

Results matching OP desired output (aside from sorting) but my assumption is the plan is the filter out the nulls in the end anyhow.

If sort needs to be exact a small edit can achieve it with an additional column, or with some more work (using a temp table or table variable) to show the exact result sorted and without the extra column, but here is what it looks like with the extra column:
[image]

PS: even though this does get the result, I think it is going to be extremely inefficient and I highly recommend NOT using this solution but instead wait for one of the other guys to do it right. I mainly did this purely to see if I could (without caring about how horribly inefficient it would be).

```
select distinct
      "ndate" =
        case
            when row_number() over(partition by t1."ndate" order by "Total transactions" desc) = 1
                then t1."ndate"
            else null
        end
    , "Total transactions" =
        case
            when row_number() over(partition by t1."ndate" order by "Total transactions" desc) = 1
                then "Total transactions"
            else null
        end
    , t1."category"
    , "transactions by category"
From
(
select distinct
      "ndate"
    , "category"
    , "transactions by category" = count("transaction_id") over( partition by "ndate", "category")
from transaction_table as t1
) as t1
left join
(
select distinct
      "ndate"
    , "Total transactions" = count("transaction_id") over( partition by "ndate", "category" order by "ndate")
from transaction_table as t1
) as t2
on t1."ndate" = t2."ndate"
and t1."transactions by category" = t2."Total transactions"
```

output:

[image: output:]

Comment: Considering we don't know what RDBMS the user is using, the ANSI delimit identifier , double quotes (`"`), would be a better choice; brackets (`[]`) are dialect specific.

Comment: This is what I have already done, I just want to get the correct count of transactions when I total them at a general level.

Comment: I can't comment on the main one due to lack of rep, but I see you mention only 4 transactions? I see 5 (unless you have some rule about "O" category that isn't mentioned in your question. If you can explain how we should expect 4, then I can adjust the query to suit the need.

Comment: There are 4 distinct transaction id's (111, 112, 113 and 114.)

Comment: then what is the expected output in the category column? (he is going to have multiple categories in a column)... or a pivot solution to show out a column for each category with the count of transactions for the row). We really need to know what his desired output should look like.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what you expect, but I think from reading your question that you need to `GROUP BY` category, but you only want to count a transaction_id one time if it happened to exist in 2 categories.

We can't have it both ways, so we have to choose - if we list the category in `GROUP BY` then we have to decide how to count a transaction that happens in 2 categories.

**Option 1:** Choose "first" category (shown alphabetically)

```
WITH CTE_DEDUPE AS (
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM 
    transaction_table QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY TRANSACTION_ID 
      ORDER BY 
        TRANSACTION_DT, 
        CATEGORY ASC
    ) = 1
), 
BASIC_AGGS AS (
  SELECT 
    TRANSACTION_DT, 
    CATEGORY, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT TRANSACTION_ID) as TRANSACTION_ID_COUNTDISTINCT, 
    COUNT(1) AS AGG_ROW_COUNT 
  FROM 
    CTE_DEDUPE 
  GROUP BY 
    TRANSACTION_DT, 
    CATEGORY
) 
SELECT 
  BASIC_AGGS.TRANSACTION_DT, 
  BASIC_AGGS.CATEGORY, 
  BASIC_AGGS.TRANSACTION_ID_COUNTDISTINCT 
FROM 
  BASIC_AGGS
```

**Result:**

| TRANSACTION_DT | CATEGORY | TRANSACTION_ID_COUNTDISTINCT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | F | 1 |
| 12 | F | 1 |
| 13 | M | 1 |

There are other options but I will hold off until you tell us some more information about what you expect, and what specific instance of SQL you are running. I generated the SQL with [Rasgo](https://www.rasgoml.com/data-analysis-tutorials) but I have that running on Snowflake right now, and the more complex we get with your solution might mean the syntax is slightly different depending on your system.

Edit: the markdown syntax is giving me issues in preview vs what the post renders as...

Answer (score 0):

Close to what you want, just presented in a slightly different way.

Use `case` *expressions* to do conditional aggregation.

```
select ndate,
       sum(case when category = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as f_category,
       sum(case when category = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as m_category,
       sum(case when category = 'O' then 1 else 0 end) as o_category,
       count(distinct transaction_id) total_transactions
from transaction_table
group by ndate;
```

Core ANSI SQL-2016. I.e. expected to execute on any dbms.